# show values of a table

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I've got a question. I build a table from a form, and I store the values in a mysql database. The form is working, I see the values in the table but when I check an other browser I don't see them. I think something is missing but I dont know what. Could you help me please ? Here is my code :

the form file :

```
<form method="post" action="file.php">
<p class="titre">Informations</p>
<fieldset id="infos">
  <p id="gender"><label>gender : </label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="M." />M.
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Ms" />Ms
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Mrs" />Mrs
  </p>
  <label>name : </label>
    <input type="text" name="name" size="30" /><br />
  <label>Address : </label>
    <input type="text" name="address" size="30" /><br />
  <label>zip code : </label>
    <input type="text" name="zipcode" size="30" /><br />
  <label>city : </label>
    <input type="text" name="city" size="30" /><br />
  <label>country : </label>
    <select name="country">
      <option value="france">France</option>
      <option value="belgium">Belgium</option>
      <option value="uk">uk</option>
    </select>
<p id="interests"><label>interests : </label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="sport" />Sport
    <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="cinema" />Cinéma<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="internet" />Internet
    <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="travel" />Voyages
  </p>
</fieldset>
<p class="titre">Message</p>
<fieldset id="message">
  <textarea name="comments" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
</fieldset>
<p id="buttons">
  <input type="submit" value="send" />
  <input type="reset" value="reset" />
</p>
</form>
```

and the php file :

```
<?php

define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost'); // serveur mysql
define('DB_SERVER_USERNAME', 'root'); // nom d'utilisateur
define('DB_SERVER_PASSWORD', 'xxxx'); // mot de passe
define('DB_DATABASE', 'formulaire'); // nom de la base

$connect = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, 
DB_SERVER_PASSWORD) 
or die('Impossible to connect : ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $connect);
$msg_erreur = "Error. Request fields:
<br/><br/>";
$msg_ok = "your request is sent.";
$message = $msg_erreur;
// vérification des champs 
if (empty($_POST['gender'])) 
  $message .= "your gender<br/>";
if (empty($_POST['name'])) 
  $message .= "your name<br/>";
if (empty($_POST['address'])) 
  $message .= "your address<br/>";
if (empty($_POST['zipcodde'])) 
  $message .= "your zipcode<br/>";
if (empty($_POST['city'])) 
  $message .= "your city<br/>";
if (empty($_POST['comments'])) 
  $message .= "your message<br/>";


if (strlen($message) > strlen($msg_erreur)) {

  echo $message;


} else {

  foreach($_POST as $index => $valeur) {
    $$index = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($valeur));
  }

  $interets = $_POST['interets'];
  $sqlinterets = '';
  for ($i=0; $i<count($interets); $i++)
  {
    $sqlinterets .= $interets[$i];
    $sqlinterets .= ', ';
  }

  $sql = "INSERT INTO formulaire VALUES ('', '".$gender."', '".$name."', 
    '".$address."', '".$zipcode."', '".$city."', '".$country."',
    '".$sqlinterests."', '".$comments."', now())";
  $res = mysql_query($sql);

}
?>
<?php
   $name = $_POST['gender'];
   //this takes the data from input
    $from = $_POST['name'];
    $car = $_POST['address'];
    echo "<table><tr><td>Name</td><td>From</td><td>Car</td></tr>
    <tr><td>".$gender."</td><td>".$name."</td><td>".$address."</td></tr></table>";
    ?>
```

Comment: php code doesn't respond for stack fiddles

Comment: "an other browser" ? what do you mean ? which browser works and which doesn't... any errors in JS console or in php_errors.log ? Also, you should translate your code before posting it... it will help non-french readers...

Comment: I edit the code. I'm adding values from safari. When I click on submit button, I see my values in the table. But when I'm looking the url on chrome, the table is empty.

Comment: I don't see any `SELECT` query in your code. So How do you think the table will be filled? On another browser the `$_POST` var is empty because the form hasn't been sent on that browser... BTW... DON'T use `mysql_` functions anymore! Really don't